# Resubscribe to Publication List

Tags: marketing-cloud, automationstudio, import, publicationlist

I have an automation that extracts a specific set of records, daily, with the end goal of having their status in a publication list updated from 'Unsubscribed' to 'Active.' All steps of the automation work as intended, including the import of the file to the target publication list. What isn't working is updating the record's status in the target publication list.

For the file that's being imported to the publication list I have three columns:

SubscriberKey
EmailAddress
Active (Populated with 'Active')
If the user is unsubscribed from 'All Subscribers' do they first need to be reactivated there before the publication list status can be changed or can they be updated independently of each other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All Subscriber List need to be updated first with Status as active. Consider below scenario:

Subscriber 1:
1: unsubscribe in all sub list
2: Activated in publication list via import
3. When you send the email out to this subscriber, it wont be sent out, as Marketing Cloud will check the status first in All Sub List.